# Do aircraft manufacturers take steps to prevent pests like geckos from damaging the electronics?

Tags: safety, aircraft-maintenance

Many Australians are suffering huge bills due to geckos getting into the circuit boards of their air conditioning units. Of course this is highly profitable for A/C manufacturers as they supply replacement boards on a virtually annual basis. I noticed in my unit that a simple fine mesh would have been sufficient to keep them out of the critical space where the circuit boards are.

My question is: do aircraft have the same potential problem and are aircraft manufacturers taking any steps to prevent this?

Comment: It isn't typically a problem for aircraft that are used often, as the electronics aren't easily accessible from outside. The bigger problem is aircraft that sit a while can get bird nests, rat nests, squirrels, etc which can cause damage to the engine/electrical systems. I would suggest editing your question to focus on any kind of pest problem (not just Geckos).

Comment: The [German government](https://theaviationist.com/2018/11/30/german-air-force-a340-carrying-angela-merkel-to-g20-performs-emergency-landing-german-chancellor-resumes-travel-in-a-commercial-flight/) can confirm that planes can suffer from pest infestations. Although i can imagine that atleast the bigger airports take measures to prevent pests from being a problem for parked planes.

Comment: Blocked pitot and static tubes tend to be the biggest safety concern, as those are exposed to the outside air. Most aircraft electronics are in their own cases, which pests are very unlikely to get into.